# How to put 2 figures on the same page?

Tags: diagrams

I have the following figures which need to be on 1 page, but it creates a separate page for each figure, I don't know why?

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{HIV-AIDSIII.pdf}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\caption{$p=0.3$, $q=0.4$, $r=0.5$, $\xi_1 =0.001$, $\xi_2 =0.003$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 3.204$.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{HIV-AIDSIV.pdf}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\caption{Density plotted against time for HIV-AIDS model with $S\left(0\right)=50$, $I_1\left(0\right)=0.50$, $I_2\left(0\right)=50$, $J\left(0\right)=20$ and $A\left(0\right)=20$.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: In this case you probably should put *both* includegraphics in the same `figure` float and use `captionof` to give each of them their own caption...

Comment: just delete the central `\end{figure} \begin{figure}[!htb]\centering`  so they are in a single float  (note that `[htb]` omits `p` so makes the figure floating to the end of document more likely.

Comment: apart from putting them in one figure the main reason they would not go on a page is that you were preventing them from being placed on a float page with the optional argument. also note `\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}` has no effect at all if you set it inside the float, this is a global parameter used in the output routine for making up the page.